# Google Charts' labels disappear when resizing in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

Here is an example in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sam_n_johnston/UhE5e/) where the chart resize when the window changes size. It works correctly under Firefox. When the chart is loaded in IE8, everything seems fine at first, but when the windows is resized, the x and y labels disappear.

Here is the code that resizes the chart:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
    });
});
```

I can't show an image of the result in IE8 because of the 10 point limit, but

- Mushrooms
- Onions
- Olives
- Zucchini
- Pepperoni

as well as the number on the left have disappeared.

Would anyone know a workaround or a solution to this problem?

Comment: It resized fine when I tested in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the chart options seems to have resolved the issue. It now resizes fine in IE8.

```
'chartArea':{left:75,top:50,width:'100%', height: '80%'}
```